# How to rearrange the object value to be part of its list value in Angular 8

Tags: angular

Below is the data I want to rearrange.

```
[
 { 
   ...,
   id: 1,
   value: [
        {geoLat: 123123, geoLong: 123432},
        {geoLat: 23240, geoLong: 234324},
        {geoLat: 23240, geoLong: 234324},
   ]
 }
 {
   ...,
   id: 2,
   value: [
        {geoLat: 653, geoLong: 435},
        {geoLat: 12321, geoLong: 987987},
   ],
   ...

 }
]
```

I'm hoping to seek for a function to assign or combine the particular 2 values so that when I do _chain() and group() I can get the following result.

```
[
 { 
   ...,
   value: [
        {geoLat: 123123, geoLong: 123432, id: 1},
        {geoLat: 23240, geoLong: 234324, id: 1},
        {geoLat: 23240, geoLong: 234324, id: 1},
   ],
   ...
 }
 {
   ...,
   value: [
        {geoLat: 653, geoLong: 435, id: 2},
        {geoLat: 12321, geoLong: 987987, id: 2},
   ],
   ...
 }
]
```

Comment: What are chain() and group()?

Comment: stack overflow is not a code writing service.  Please read the following documentation, then edit and rephrase the question.  [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` to achieve this.

Here is a working example.

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  value: [{
      geoLat: 123123,
      geoLong: 123432
    },
    {
      geoLat: 23240,
      geoLong: 234324
    },
    {
      geoLat: 23240,
      geoLong: 234324
    }
  ]
}, {
  id: 2,
  value: [{
      geoLat: 653,
      geoLong: 435
    },
    {
      geoLat: 12321,
      geoLong: 987987
    }
  ]
}];

const newArray = data.map(x => {
  x.value.map(y => {
    y['id'] = x.id;
    return y
  });
  delete x.id;
  return x;
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: What if there is another object element before getting to the value[]. I got the value not found.

const data = [{
  id: 1,
 operatingLocationList: [
       ...,
       value: [{
      geoLat: 123123,
      geoLong: 123432
    },
    {
      geoLat: 23240,
      geoLong: 234324
    },
    {
      geoLat: 23240,
      geoLong: 234324
    }
  ]
]
}, {
  id: 2,
  value: [{
      geoLat: 653,
      geoLong: 435
    },
    {
      geoLat: 12321,
      geoLong: 987987
    }
  ]
}];

Answer (score 0):

```js
data.forEach((elem) => {
    elem.value.forEach((pos) =>
        pos['id'] = elem.id
    );
    delete elem.id;
});
```